# Proving the Irrationality of this Number

Tags: nt.number-theory

I found this problem on Math.SE:

> Prove that $\log_35+\log_25$ is irrational.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/986227/173397.

I labored on it for a few days, and couldn't find an algebraic solution- I'm not even sure if such a solution exists. All I was able to do was prove that both components were irrational by themselves (as opposed to their sum). I am wondering if anyone has seen this problem before, and/or if anyone knows a solution. If so, I could really use a hint.

So far, using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (i.e., all integers have a unique prime factorization) hasn't helped me the way one would use it to show that the individual components are irrational.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To make this question more self contained, I would recommend giving the number itself.

Comment: Will do. Editing it now.

Comment: One would expect this sum to be transcendental, but even proving irrationality of the sum of two given transcendental numbers tends to be hard.

Comment: Incidentally, Schanuel's conjecture would imply that this number is transcendental.

Comment: This won't help much, but you can rewrite the number as $(\log5\log6)/(\log2\log3)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah, I've tried that to no avail, unfortunately. I guess one strategy I haven't attempted (yet) would be to express the sum as a Taylor series a lá Fourier for $e$, and then look for that contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

To resonate with Henry Cohn's comment, [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) implies that the natural logarithms of the primes are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, the statement in the original post is probably true, but proving it might be out of reach at the moment.